# Please show the tags associated with each question listed in the "Related Questions" section of the "Ask a Question" page

Tags: feature-request, tags, search, asking-questions

I think it would be very handy if we were able to see the tags associated with each question listed in the "Related Questions" section of the "Ask a Question" page.

### Use case

I was asking a question titled "Return statements in Ruby", intending on getting feedback for best-practices for ruby return statements (as they are optional).

Return statements obviously flagged tons of not-aptly-titled questions, most if not all of them had nothing to do with the particular syntax of ruby.  Instead of being able to visually filter the non [ruby] tagged Related questions, I had to question whether or not this was a dupe and click on several of them to find out if they were related (no, they weren't).

Having the tags there would have saved time and reduced duplicates if my question had already been asked.

Comment: Ideally you would search to see if your question has already been asked. The list of possible related questions in the dropdown on the Ask Question page isn't meant to replace that.

Comment: There is a difference between the ideal world and the real world.  Taking a glance at the questions on stackoverflow, there are many duplicates.  This is a simple change which would _improve usability_ greatly for both question askers and answerers.

Comment: We had This discussion on meta.gaming I was going to make a request for that.

http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/821/question-with-vague-title/830#830

Comment: Marking as a dupe as the newer question is cleaner and, really, we have no progress on this front.

Answer (score 3):

Here a abstract form hour discussion in the Gaming Thread.

We agreed that questions asker are not required to add the game title in their question, the use of tag is enough.

Example : "how-can-i-kill-the-president" tag "fallout 2"

but the question "how can I beat the final boss" could be more problematic, since it's a common concept in many games. Not having this tag displayed in "Related Questions" section of the "Ask a Question" page would be useful.