# Refresh "Questions that may already have your answer" after adding tags based on these tags

Tags: feature-request, tags, related-questions, similar-questions

It happens often for me that, after submitting the answer, I look at the "Related" list on the sidebar and see questions that talk about the same question but have a title that's largely difference in words, although very close in meaning.

I know there's a "Similar Questions" list that appears while writing question body, but that's also based on text-processing, which seems to be the problem.

I suggest that, after the user adds the tags, a new "Questions that may already have your answer" list loads right above the "Post Your Question" button, and it depends not only the title and boy text, but also on tag association.

Hopefully it would be not very hard to implement, and would make users life easier.

Comment: Typically you should be sure there's no duplicates before asking, however the current related list is horrible.

Comment: I wonder why this question has been ignored by the community. Considering "don't put tags in the titles" policy, it would be very helpful to actually *use* those tags in the search. (Just was going to ask something similar myself, after some completely unrelated questions jumping up at me there). I believe that while this is one of the great features of SO, it can and should be improved. I.e., it can prioritise or filter or extend search to tags.

Comment: I came exactly to propose this. So many times the `Questions that may already have your answer` box shows good questions, but they are for e.g. Perl when I need e.g. Python.